# Having a screen as a part of another screen

Tags: react-native, animation, mobile-application

I have a requirement as in the picture, when the sidebar shows up and user presses on an item, the small screen on the right will be changed correspondingly, for example if I press on "Item 2", the small screen will show item2's screen, and when I press on the small screen, app will navigate to that screen. I've beeb searching for keywords like "screen in screen", "2 screens at a time" but nothing comes up, does anyone have a keyword for me?

[screen in scren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMSO9.png)

Comment: You can show the screen conditionally onPress. Something like `{isButtonClicked ? return ( </ YourScreen>) : null}`

Comment: Will it take lots of performance (app becomes laggy) if I load it like that? I mean i know if I use a picture it will be a lot easier, but the content of that screen will not real time.

Comment: Yeah, this might take a lot of performance, the screen might re-render for every click to show.